# Count items by condition with XML and PHP?

Tags: php, xml, count, get, conditional-statements

I would like to get the count of only items inside this file with `sellingstatus->sellingstate` of `EndedWithSales` ONLY, and perhaps also get the count for `EnededWithoutSales`.

```
<sellingStatus>
    <currentPrice currencyId="USD">25.0</currentPrice>
    <convertedCurrentPrice currencyId="USD">25.0</convertedCurrentPrice>
    <bidCount>1</bidCount>
    <sellingState>EndedWithSales</sellingState>
</sellingStatus>
```

How would I go about passing this argument in php?

Here is a link to the sample of XML: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/Samples/findCompletedItems_basic_out_xml.txt.

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you need to access the url thu `file_get_contents`, Consider this example:

```
$url = 'http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/Samples/findCompletedItems_basic_out_xml.txt';

// access the url and get that file
$contents = file_get_contents($url);

// convert it to an xml object
$contents = simplexml_load_string($contents);

$count = 0; // initialize counter

// loop and search for that
foreach($contents->searchResult->item as $key => $value) {

    if(isset($value->sellingStatus->sellingState) && $value->sellingStatus->sellingState == 'EndedWithSales') {
        // if that key exists and is contains EndedWithSales, increment it
        $count++;
    }
}

// at the end of the loop echo it or whatever you wanted to do
echo "<script>alert('You have $count ocurrances of EndedWithSales in this XML');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the XML into an DOMDocument, create an Xpath instance for it an just fetch the count.

```
$url = 'http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/Samples/findCompletedItems_basic_out_xml.txt';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($url);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// register a prefix for the namespace used in the document 
$xpath->registerNamespace('ebay', 'http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services');

var_dump(
   $xpath->evaluate(
     'count(
       //ebay:searchResult[1]
       /ebay:item[
         ebay:sellingStatus/ebay:sellingState = "EndedWithSales"
       ]
      )'
   )
);
```

Output:

```
double(2)
```

Xpaths `count()` function returns the number of nodes in defined by an expression.

The first `searchResult` element in the document:

`//ebay:searchResult[1]`

The `item` elements in the first `searchResult`

`//ebay:searchResult[1]/ebay:item`

Items with a `sellingState` "EndedWithSales"

`//ebay:searchResult[1]/ebay:item[ebay:sellingStatus/ebay:sellingState = "EndedWithSales"]`